# Why doesn't scala enumeration not pick values from other enum as its value?

Tags: scala, inheritance, enumeration

I am trying to understand why the scala enumeration does not pick values from other enum types, when created as a value in it. Say I have the following

```
trait SchemaBase extends Enumeration {

  implicit def valueToVal(x: Value): Val = x.asInstanceOf[Val]

  case class Val(name: String, dataType: DataType, nullable: Boolean) extends super.Val {
    val col: Column = functions.col(name)
  }

  protected def column(name: String, dataType: DataType, nullable: Boolean = true): SchemaBase.Val = {
    Val(name, dataType, nullable).asInstanceOf[SchemaBase.Val]
  }

object SchemaBase extends SchemaBase
```

Now if I create `Enumeration`s `AScehma` and `BSchema` like below:

```
object ASchema extends SchemaBase {
  val Id: SchemaBase.Val = column("a_id", IntegerType)
  val BName: SchemaBase.Val = BSchema.Name
}

object BSchema extends SchemaBase {
  val Name: SchemaBase.Val = column("b_name", StringType)
}
```

Here `ASchema.BName` won't be available in `ValueSet` of `ASchema`.

I understand `BName`is an enumeration value of `BSchema`, and know of an approach to solve this problem, but would like to know **why** this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Each call to a Value method adds a new unique value to the enumeration.](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Enumeration.html)

That should really be "*the* `Value` constructor", and of course the call 
can be indirect (e.g. `column` calls `SchemaBase.Val` constructor which calls `Enumeration.Val` constructor which calls `Enumeration.Value` constructor). As the next sentence says, it's simply convention that

> these values are usually defined as val members of the enumeration.

You are free to have any other members, or not define some or all values as `val`s. And

```
val BName: SchemaBase.Val = BSchema.Name
```

doesn't call the `Value` constructor (either `ASchema`'s or `BSchema`'s). That's it.